# Spring - How can I @Autowire an object inside a @Component class?

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception

I am creating a 2 class library. The main class (*CustomLogger*) will be used by my application. The helper class (*LoggerConfig*) is there to import some fields from a .*properties* file used by *CustomLogger*. When I run my code below, my Autowired config object stays null. Any advice would be appreciated.

CustomLogger.java:

```
@Component
public class CustomLogger {
    private String env;
    @Autowired
    private LoggerConfig myConfig;
    public CustomLogger() {
        this.env = myConfig.env;   // <-- getting null pointer exception here
    }
}
// ... public void methods here
```

LoggerConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("logger")
public class LoggerConfig {
     public string env; // represented as 'logger.env' in properties
     public void setEnv(final String env) { this.env = env; }
     // ... other fields
}
```

Controller.java (using the library)

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @Autowired private CustomLogger customLogger;
// GET mappings
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `@Autowired` annotation according to documentation

> Fields are injected right after construction of a bean, before any config methods are invoked. Such a config field does not have to be public.
> Autowired Methods.

So for property autowiring it will create a object of the class using default consructor and only after the object is created the dependencies are injected . So in your case in `CustomLogger` during object creation the `myConfig` is not injected yet and so it is null which leads to NPE.

This can be resolved by going for dependency injection using constructors

```java
@Component
public class CustomLogger {
    private final String env;
    private final LoggerConfig myConfig;
    @Autowired
    // Note : @Autowired is not really necessary for constructor autowiring in newer versions of spring
    public CustomLogger(LoggerConfig config) {
        this.myConfig = config;
        this.env = myConfig.env;  
    }
}
```

in which case the object is created along with its dependencies

Answer (score -1):

##### Summary

The question may be  how to build a custom autowired properties config in `Spring`?
I think that you can try to follow the step below , that may be  helpful for you.

- 1. Define a Custom properties class
- 2. Add the config file `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json`
- 3. Wired the value which you define in step1  with spring properties
- 4. Create a Configuration class and wired the Bean into SpringContext

###### 1. Define a Custom properties class

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "logger")
@Data
@Primary
public class LoggerConfig {
     public string env; // represented as 'logger.env' in properties
    // ... other fields
}
```

###### 2. Add the config file `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json`

Define the spring file `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` to indicate springContext that  which properties should be wired ; You should ad d the `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` to your `project path`    that is `src/main/resources/META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json`
Below is code snippet

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "loggerConfig",
      "type": "com.statckoverflow.properties.LoggerConfig",
      "sourceType": "com.statckoverflow.properties.LoggerConfig",
    }
  ],
  "properties": [
   
    {
      "name": "logger.env",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "sourceType": "com.statckoverflow.properties.LoggerConfig",
      "description": "logger env."
    }
  ]
}
```

###### 3. Wired the value which you define in step1  with spring properties

Checkout your spring yaml or properties path , ensure that is in your resource path and then configurate  config which is define in previous  step
the code snippet

- properties

```
logger.env = develop
```

###### 4. Create a Configuration class and wired the Bean into SpringContext

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LoggerConfig.class})
@Slf4j
public class Config {
    @Bean
    private LoggerConfig applyLoggerConfig(@Autowired LoggerConfig config){
//  you can add some custom  configuration here 
       return config;
}
```

If you have no more custom configuration , just ignore the step4 , use the `@Autowired`  to get Bean.
Hopes it could be helpful for you;